# warning: disabled expansion of recursive macro

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, gdcm

I am currently building the `GDCM` project using `MacOSX` default compiler: `clang`. This compiler trigger a warning in its own header (see [ref](https://open.cdash.org/viewBuildError.php?type=1&buildid=4184396)):

```
In file included from /Users/builder/external/GDCM/Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmJPEG12Codec.cxx:21:
/Users/builder/external/GDCM/Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmJPEGBITSCodec.cxx:336:9: warning: disabled expansion of recursive macro [-Wdisabled-macro-expansion]
    if (setjmp(jerr.setjmp_buffer))
        ^
/Users/builder/llvm/llvm-rel-install/bin/../include/c++/v1/setjmp.h:40:21: note: expanded from macro 'setjmp'
#define setjmp(env) setjmp(env)
                    ^
In file included from /Users/builder/external/GDCM/Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmJPEG12Codec.cxx:21:
/Users/builder/external/GDCM/Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmJPEGBITSCodec.cxx:724:9: warning: disabled expansion of recursive macro [-Wdisabled-macro-expansion]
    if (setjmp(jerr.setjmp_buffer))
        ^
/Users/builder/llvm/llvm-rel-install/bin/../include/c++/v1/setjmp.h:40:21: note: expanded from macro 'setjmp'
#define setjmp(env) setjmp(env)
                    ^
2 warnings generated.
```

This is either a clear bug in llvm header (which I find hard to believe), or I am missing something about the use of `setjmp` in `C++98`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's neither. It's not a bug in an LLVM header, it's not that you're missing something about the use of `setjmp`, it's that you've enabled a warning that happens to also trigger on perfectly valid code. Most warnings do. That's why they're warnings rather than errors. This particular warning happens to mostly trigger on valid code. That's why it's not enabled by default, not even included in `-Wall`, and not even included in `-Wextra`. Yet you enabled it anyway. That's fine, but then you should be prepared to deal with the results.

Comment: No, this is not necessarily consciously enabled. It might be enab led by default by the build environment. E.g. it is by default enabled for building Debian packages.